# Does this sentence sound ok? "this" or "those"

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, complementation, demonstrative-pronouns

This sentence is an summarization after a meeting for three people:

> We three agreed on those two problems will be an interesting problem
>   to study next.

I want to state the following fact:

1. We agree those two problems is interesting
2. We will study those two problems from now on.

I feel weird on reading this sentence...Any improvement can you guys suggest?

Moreover, should I say `this two problems` or `those two problems`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is for singular, and these for plural, so the correct one is these or those (two is plural).

Answer (score 0):

**We three** agreed that those two problems would be interesting to study next.
OR
**The three of us** agreed that those two problems would be interesting to study next.
We are talking about **two problems** here, and you have used '**on**' after '**agreed**' incorrectly.
In simple non-grammatical lingo, there is something wrong with the way you have connected two different sentences as one.

example. (something that goes on like the first sentence in my answer and makes sense)
We three agreed on the merits of globalization and decided that it would be an interesting topic to study.